# Are the graphs of these two functions equal to each other?

Tags: functions

The functions are: $y=\frac{x^2-4}{x+2}$ and $(x+2)y=x^2-4$.

I've seen this problem some time ago, and the official answer was that they are not.
My question is: Is that really true?

The functions obviously misbehave when $x = -2$, but aren't both of them indeterminate forms at that point? Why are they different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(1)$The first function is undefined at $x = -2$,

$(2)$ the second equation **is defined** at $x = -2$:

$$(x + 2) y = x^2 - 4 \iff xy + 2y = x^2 - 4\tag{2}$$ It's graph includes the entire line $x = -2$. At $x = -2$, all values of y are defined, so every point lying on the line $x = -2$: each of the form $(-2, y)$ are included in the graph of function (2). Not so with the first equation.

ADDED:

Just to see how well Wolfram Alpha took on the challenge:

**Graph of Equation $(1)$:** (It fails to show the omission at $x = -2$) But it does add:

[image]

[image]

**Graph of Equation $(2)$:**

[image]

Note: The pair of graphs included here do not match in terms of the scaling of the axes, so the line $y = x - 2$ looks sloped differently in one graph than in the other.

Comment: I'm sorry if this looks dumb, but I've been told that if a number is equal to $0/0$, then it can assume any value. I can't see why there isn't a asymptote on the first function too.

Comment: Carpe: But the second equation does not evaluate to $0/0$. When $x = -2$, y can be any value whatsoever, so the line containing all points $(-2, y)$ defined by $x = - 2$ is part of its graph.

Comment: There is no asymptote at $x = -2$ because the function described in the first equation has values that approach $-4$ as $x$ approaches 2 "from above or below".  A vertical asymptote would be due to the function tending to infinity as $x$ approaches 2, which does not happen here.

Comment: Alas, not before I started typing, which I guess I don't do fast enough... (I saw your last edit appear as I was still finishing.)

Comment: Is this clear now, Carpe?  Sorry you experienced confusion. I hope we've cleared things up a bit! ;-)  $\quad0/0\;$ IS indeed, undefined. And particularly, division of any number by zero is undefined!!  But that's not a problem for the second equation. So the functions differ only that in the first, there is no point at $x = -2$, whereas, in the second, there are infinitely many points, $(-2, y)$, at $x = -2$

Comment: @amWhy: you are always conscientious! +1

Comment: @amWhy: But I am missed to make +'s here. Missed that. :-(

Answer (score 3):

In the second equation, when $x=-2$, there is no restriction whatsoever on $y$. The graph of the second equation includes the entire vertical line $x=-2$.

Comment: Why isn't there a line on the first one too?
$y = 0/0$ isn't true for every $y$?

Comment: Thus, the second equation does not describe a function...

Comment: $y$ isn't defined at $x=-2$ in the first equation. The graph of the first equation is like that of $y=x-2$ but with a hole at $x=-2$.

Comment: Khan Academy lied to me?

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to that

Comment: @Carpe Noctem  The distinction is that in the first equation, $y = f(x)$ has no definition at $ x = -2$ ($0/0$ is undefined because it is indeterminate), while in the second equation, the graph is actually a composite of two "curves", one of which is not the graph of a function (because $x = -2$ works _regardless_ of the value of $y$).  [And sorry, but _not even_ KhanAcademy knows everything... ;) ]

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've watched this video a long time ago: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/functions_and_graphs/undefined_indeterminate/v/undefined-and-indeterminate

I thought $0/0$ was defined (to be every possible value, for some reason), but now I see that it is undefined too.

Answer (score 1):

Forget functions for a moment.  An equation is a sentence, and the graph of an equation (in two variables) is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ which satisfy the sentence.  So $(1, -\frac{1}{3})$ is in the graph of the equation $y = \frac{x^2 -4}{x+2}$ and $(x+2)y = x^2-4$.  You can see this by plugging in $x = 1$ and $y = -1/3$ -- each sentence is true.

The point $(-2, 0)$ lies in the graph of the second equation, but not in the first, because $\frac{0}{0}$ is a nonsense phrase (i.e. "undefined").  It doesn't make sense to call nonsense like $y = \frac{0}{0}$ true or false.  Moreover, $(-2, 3)$ and $(-2, 4)$ also satisfy the second sentence.  In fact, ANY pair $(-2, y)$ satisfies the second equation, so all those points lie on the graph of the second equation.

Now let's return to functions.  The first equation is the graph of a function.  The second equation is not, because it fails the vertical line test.  To be really nit-picky, a function is a rule which assigns to each element of the domain a unique element of the range.  So an equation is not a function.

Finally, "indeterminate forms" concern limits, which don't seem immediately relevant here.